# How to make something visible in a form by checking a variable?

Tags: vb.net, math

i'm making a childrens maths program and what I have in mind is setting a global variable and once a child has gone through and learnt what is on each form I would set a variable such as teacher = true. After this is set and the child returns back to the mainpage a hidden section will become visible i'm not sure how to make that section visible and i'm not sure if it's because i'm not using the right way of doing this or not declaring the global variables correctly

Currently for the global variables i just put

```
Public Teacher As Boolean
```

At the top of my mainpage

I don't know where I should put on the mainpage for when it opens up to do a check of the variable to see whether or not it is true or false and then to execute the code that I want it to execute.

This is what i currently have

```
Private Sub Mainpage_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    If Teacher = True Then
        aboutpage.Visible = True
    Else
        aboutpage.Visible = False
    End If
End Sub
```

That's for the loading of the mainpage but it doesn't show the about page if teacher is = true

Here is what i had for changing teacher to true or false

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Me.Close()
    Enabled11.Show()
    Mainpage.Show()
    Teacher = True
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Me.Close()
    Teacher = False
    Mainpage.Show()
End Sub
```

I have a feeling it's the variable but i'm not sure what I did wrong is there anyone here who has contact details for instant messaging who could help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is almost how you can do it, the only problem is the `Load` event will only fire the first time you open a specific instance of a form. Either try to use the `Activate` event or try something like this:

Add a public member to your `Mainpage` form (might include bugs, haven't written VB.net in several years):

```
Public Sub ToggleTeacher(toggle as Boolean)
    aboutpage.Visible = toggle
End Sub
```

In your other form, you'd then just call this sub rather than modifying `Teacher`:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Me.Close()
    Enabled11.Show()
    Mainpage.ToggleTeacher(True);
    Mainpage.Show()
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Me.Close()
    Mainpage.ToggleTeacher(False);
    Mainpage.Show()
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried that it didnt do anything did a direct copy and paste of it it's not making aboutpage.visible = true @Mario

Comment: Nevermind I figured out how the code works and just had to change toggle to true thank you so much @mario

Comment: Yeah, "toggle" might be a bit misleading. `ShowTeacher()` might be a better name.